# SQL - fetch records based on a condition of two columns

Tags: sql

I need to fetch records where
Order No = ABC
has more than one tracking number in a large table 
Can someone help with that?

Comment: `WHERE Col1 = Col2 AND Col1 <> Col3`?

Comment: what is the primary key of the table or ddl if possible

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  As written, it is too ambiguous/broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that you're fetching records from `Orders` and the "large table" is `TrackingNumbers`.  You can `group by` the OrderNo in a sub-query and refine the sub-query by using a `having` clause.  Then the sub-query will return only `OrderNo`s that are in the table more than once.  For example:

```
select OrderNo
  from Orders
 where OrderNo in (select OrderNo
                     from TrackingNumbers
                    group by OrderNo
                   having count(*) > 1)
```

To identify duplicates in a single table (as mentioned in the comments):

```
select *
  from Orders
 group by TrackingNumber
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Actually OrderNo and TrackingNumber are both in the same table (Orders) - I am looking for OrderNumbers that have repeating records with multiple tracking numbers. Technically, each order should only have one tracking number and so I am looking for duplication.